What's wrong with my code to convert a matrix to and from a byte string?
I have this function to convert a binary 2d array to a byte array:
def flatten_and_pad_to_multiple_of_8(binary_matrix):
    # Step 1: Calculate the size of the original flattened array
    rows, cols = binary_matrix.shape
    current_length = rows * cols
    
    # Step 2: Calculate the required length that is a multiple of 8
    padded_length = ((current_length + 7) // 8) * 8
    
    # Step 3: Initialize flat_bits with the required padded length
    flat_bits = np.zeros(padded_length, dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # Step 4: Fill flat_bits with values from the binary matrix
    idx = 0
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            flat_bits[idx] = binary_matrix[i, j]
            idx += 1
    
    return flat_bits

def matrix_to_ascii(matrix):
    flat_bits = flatten_and_pad_to_multiple_of_8(matrix)    
    # Convert the flattened bits into bytes
    ascii_string = ""
    for i in range(0, len(flat_bits), 8):
        byte = 0
        for j in range(8):
            byte = (byte << 1) | flat_bits[i + j]
        ascii_char = chr(byte)
        ascii_string += ascii_char
    return ascii_string

If
matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)

then matrix_to_ascii(matrix) is '}÷ß\x00' although it is a string. I then have to do matrix_to_ascii(matrix).encode(). My problem is in converting it back to a matrix.
I will first convert the string to a byte array to save space. I need to save space in my code. Here is the broken code to convert it back to a matrix:
def ascii_to_matrix(byte_array, original_shape):
    """
    ascii_string must be a bytestring before it is passed in.
    """
    # Initialize the binary matrix with the original shape
    rows, cols = original_shape
    binary_matrix = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    # Fill the binary matrix with bits from the byte array
    bit_idx = 0
    for byte in byte_array:
        for j in range(8):
            if bit_idx < rows * cols:
                binary_matrix[bit_idx // cols, bit_idx % cols] = (byte >> (7 - j)) & 1
                bit_idx += 1
            else:
                break
    return binary_matrix

Unfortunately, it gives the wrong output:
ascii_to_matrix(matrix_to_ascii(matrix).encode(), (5, 5))

array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)

What am I doing wrong?
(I am not using any fancier numpy functions as I will want to speed this all up with numba. In particular, I can't use packbits or tobytes as they are not supported by numba. I also can't use bytes or bytearray.)

"I also can't use bytes or bytearray." - how are you hoping to write a function that outputs a bytestring, if you cannot use the bytestring type?

@user2357112 b'hello' is supported. It's just the functions that aren't.

You really shouldn't call non-ASCII strings "ascii".

@nocomment Yes. That is a mistake.

Your ascii_to_matrix seems to work fine if you encode your string to a 1-byte-per-character encoding; .encode() defaults to UTF-8, and some of the characters in your matrix's "text" representation will end up being two bytes in UTF-8.
print(x := matrix_to_ascii(matrix))
print(f"{x.encode()=!r}")
print(f"{x.encode('iso-8859-1')=!r}")
print(z := ascii_to_matrix(x.encode("iso-8859-1"), matrix.shape))
assert np.array_equal(matrix, z)

prints out
}÷ß
x.encode()=b'}\xc3\xb7\xc3\x9f\x00'
x.encode('iso-8859-1')=b'}\xf7\xdf\x00'
[[0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]

– note how the default encoding is not the same as the single-byte encoding.

Thank you! And from a human being too :)

import numpy as np

matrix = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    ],
    dtype=np.uint8,
)


def matrix_to_bytes(matrix):
    flat_matrix = matrix.flatten()
    chunks = np.pad(flat_matrix, (0, 8 - len(flat_matrix) % 8)).reshape(-1, 8)
    return bytes(int("".join(map(str, chunk)), 2) for chunk in chunks)


def bytes_to_matrix(bytestring, shape):
    bits = "".join(f"{byte:08b}" for byte in bytestring)
    return np.array(list(bits), dtype=np.uint8)[: np.prod(shape)].reshape(shape)


print(x := matrix_to_bytes(matrix))
print(y := bytes_to_matrix(x, (5, 5)))
assert np.array_equal(matrix, y)

seems to do the trick.
Note there's no conversion to "ASCII" (since this matrix wouldn't be expressible as 7-bit ASCII anyway).

Thank you but I can't use bytes either because of numba. Is it possible to fix the code I provided?  It's a good point that this is not ASCII.

Well, your implementation likely wouldn't be improved much by using Numba anyway, since it's not really using any vectorized features...

I find that every function call is expensive in python/numpy.

Nested for loops will be much, much more expensive.

That is true, except for in numba where they are very fast.
